# Algorithm to find a group seating arrangement for an open book test

Tags: algorithm

You are planning the group seating arrangement for a open book test given a list of students, V from different schools to participate. Assuming the fact that students who are known to each other directly or indirectly will probably cheat more as compared to unknown people sitting together. 
Suppose you are also given a lookup table T where T[u] for u ? V is a list of students that u knows. If u knows v, then v knows u. You are required to arrange the seating such that any student at a table doesn't knows any other student sitting at the same table either directly or through some other student sitting at the same table. For example, if x knows y, and y knows z, then x, y, z can sit at the same table. Describe an efficient algorithm that, given V and T, returns the minimum number of tables needed to achieve this requirement. Analyze the running time of your algorithm.

Comment: Good start typing in the homework question. Next step to type in the answer :-) It is a process called *Learning*

Comment: While the question is interesting - we don't like to be given orders. You described **your** task. Now tell us what did you try, and what exactly is the question you are asking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

Follow a student relations out to two edges, get a graph:

```
a - e - j
      \ q

b - d
  \ t

r - w - x - y - z
```

All the students in the same subgraph have to be separated, so the minimum number of tables is one for each students in the largest group - in this example the largest subgraph is `r-w-x-y-z`, so 5 tables.

Untested Python pseudocode:

```
# Given a student list
# a b c d e f j q r t w x y z

# start a chain at a
# a b c d e f j q r t w x y z
# .

# visit friends of a
# a b c d e f j q r t w x y z
# .       .

# visit friends of a's friends
# a b c d e f j q r t w x y z
# .       .   . .

# if e and j are friends, don't double-count

# Get a count of 4 starting at person a
# Repeat for all students
# Report the longest chain.

friendCounts = {}

def countFriendsOf(T, student, friendTracker, moreSteps=2):
    friendTracker[student] = True #quicker to set it regardless,
                                  #than to check if it's set
    if not moreSteps:
        return

    for friend in T[student]:
        countFriendsOf(T, friend, friendTracker, moreSteps - 1)

    return friendTracker


for u in V:
    friends = countFriendsOf(T, u, friendTracker={})
    friendCounts[u] = (len(friends), friends)

results = sorted(friendCounts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0], reverse=True)
(student, (friendCount, friends)) = results[0]

print "The smallest number of tables is:", friendCount
print "Mandated by the friend group of:", student
print

from pprint import pprint
pprint(friends)
```

> Analyze the running time of your algorithm.

Analysis: Fine on any computer more powerful than a snowglobe.

Not sure. Best case: students have no friends - linear with respect to number of students. O(n). Worst case: every student is friends with every other student, then it does lookups for every student for every student, so O(n^3). Ew.

It was running more like O(n^2) until I realised that version was definitely wrong.

This version is only not-definitely-wrong, it isn't definitely-right.

I didn't even start it as a recursive solution, it just ended up going that way. friendTracker use is a nasty side-effect, and the recursive call is not tail recursion optimizable. Not that Python does that,